# Transition from an elliptical orbit to circular orbit

Tags: energy, orbital-motion, space, satellites

This is just a small problem that I was wondering about.

Supposed we have a satellite of mass 'm' in an elliptical orbit about earth of mass 'M'. Since the orbit is elliptical, the speed varies from 2 velocities: a $v_{max}$ and a $v_{min}$. This is also means that there are two elliptical radius: an $r_{max}$ and an $r_{min}$.

Now lets suppose we want to move the satellite from an elliptical orbit to a circular orbit. When it is at $r_{max}$, how much kinetic energy should be changed to achieve a circular orbit?

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll just give a pointer, which is to use the *vis-viva* equation, $v^2 = G(M+m)\left(\frac 2 r - \frac 1 a\right)$, where $M$ and $m$ are the masses of the two orbiting objects, $r$ is the distance between the two objects, and $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never actually learned the vis-viva equation. The textbook we use is the Halliday-Resnick so we haven't learned too many additional details yet. This question was imposed upon me by one of the Teacher Aids a while back, fortunately high schoolers don't get this level of HW.

Comment: Have you heard of [Hohmann transfer orbits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit)?